# GWT ToolTip -Requirement

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I am looking for tooltip/widget/popup panel  like this one [image]

Any idea for such tooltip in GWT ?? I tried ballon widget in gwt,but that does not help me,i need a tooltip like the one above that should also  be selectable!

Comment: I'm not expert in GWT, but I'm afraid you are to use **PopupPanel** and to customize it

Answer (score 0):

[PopupPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html) is certainly your best start. PopupPanel will get you an undecorated square box like your example, with user interaction.

Depending on your design requirements you can setup the content with straight HTML (embed an [HTMLPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html), with the HTML as contents, inside a PopupPanel), or lay it out using the GWT layout tool.

Also look over: [DecoratedPopupPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DecoratedPopupPanel.html) for some ideas about decorating the border of your panel with css rules. This may help with the little triangle pointer at the top.

One more hint: you might end up embedding a [FocusPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html) in your PopupPanel if you need to track events outside specific GUI elements.